# Option 'scatter' cause color not normal in pgfplots in LaTeX?

Tags: pgfplots, color, groupplots

With **pgfplots** package, we can plot several figures by **groupplot**.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={group size=2 by 2},
      width=4cm, height=4cm,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
      \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,2) (2,1)};
      \addlegendentry{one}
      \addplot[color=red,scatter,only marks, mark=o] coordinates{(1,1)};
      \addlegendentry{two}
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

How to change the scatter (`o`) to be red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you don't need a `groupplot` in order to place multiple *graphs* on the same axis. Rather, `groupplot` is used to place multiple *axes* in the same Ti*k*Z picture.

At any rate, the problem of colors is not related to `groupplot`, and instead arises because the second plot has the `scatter` option. From the PGFPlots documentation,

> The option `scatter` has a slightly misleading name as we already had a scatter plot before we added that option. It activates scatter plots with individual appearance: without further options, it chooses individual colors for every marker.

This is the graph you want:

[image: A scatter plot with three connected blue points, and one red point. The legend entry for the blue points says "one," and the legend entry for the red points says "two." The legend entries lie atop of a blue point, obscuring it from view.]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=4cm, height=4cm,
    ]
      \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,2) (2,1)};
      \addplot[color=red,only marks, mark=o] coordinates{(1,1)};
      \addlegendentry{one}
      \addlegendentry{two}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Here's a way to see more clearly why `scatter` results in the **wrong** legend colors. First, delete `width=4cm, height=4cm`, then try changing `coordinates{(1,1)}` in plot two to

```
coordinates{
         (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)
         (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5)
         (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5)
         (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5)
         (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5)
}
```

and watch what happens to the plot colors.

Comment: In what condition, we should use option `scatter`?

Comment: @Y.zeng If you try the wrong example in my answer, you'll see that PGFPlots assigns colors to the points based on their *y*-value—bigger values are more red, and smaller values are more blue. So, we should use `scatter` if we want color to represent how great or how small the values of each point are.

Comment: If you add `scatter` into the second `\addplot` with those coordinates, see what happens.

Comment: Yes. You are right.  I see it know.